# Download and 'mirror' server sites

Tags: system-installation

I want to download Ubuntu, but I can't because when I try to download 13.10 for 64-bit, I get a .iso file at about 900 mb from some weird site usually unrelated to Ubuntu. Right now, my PC (win 8) says 
"Do you want to open or save Ubuntu- 13.10-desktop-amd64.iso (883 mb) from mirrors.einstein.yu.edu"

the site is always mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

That's a valid repository at the [Albert Einstein College of Medicine](http://einstein.yu.edu/) at Yeshiva U in [the Bronx](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=bronx,%20ny&ll=40.836671,-73.863831&spn=1.83067,2.293396&hnear=Bronx,%20New%20York&t=m&z=9), so you must be in either the eastern US or Atlantic Canada.

The Ubuntu website looks at your IP, and picks the likely closest server (which is programmed to be a 'mirror' copy of the master Ubuntu file server) to deliver it to you.

As to the file size, that, too, is typical for the full-blown Ubuntu with the [Unity desktop](http://unity.ubuntu.com/). Other versions (i.e., [Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net) and [Xubuntu](http://www.xubuntu.org)) are smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your "weird site" is actually a valid Ubuntu mirror.  You can find a list of mirror sites that provide ISO images at: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors

I would suggest picking a mirror site near to you (in geographical terms) and seeing what distros. they have available for download.